# Ola Hallengren's backups scripts, cleanup only mode

Tags: backup, ola-hallengren

Is it possible to run Ola Hallengren's backup scripts in cleanup only mode? I have a couple of servers where the cleanup time was set too long, and I now have to clean up hundreds of databases worth of backups. I could bang something together with PowerShell or similar, but I'd be more comfortable with some known good code handling it instead.

Comment: Have you tried using the CleanupMode parameter and setting it to BEFORE_BACKUP?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to try this, but from what I can tell they either won't work, or will still have to do at least part of the backup process, or will require modifications to Ola's stored procedures.

## Don't back up any databases?

Looking at the code inside Ola's `DatabaseBackup` stored procedure, the cleanup portion is inside the loop that goes through all of the databases that are to be backed up. So passing a dummy parameter or just asking it to back up only a small token database isn't going to delete old backup files from the other databases.

## Backup to `NUL`?

You can pass `NUL` as the directory, but the code has a check for that and won't perform cleanup if you are writing the backups to `NUL`.

```
  IF @CleanupTime IS NOT NULL AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @Directories WHERE DirectoryPath = 'NUL')
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO @Errors ([Message], Severity, [State])
        SELECT 'The value for the parameter @CleanupTime is not supported. Cleanup is not supported when backing up to NUL.', 16, 4
  END
```

And even if you commented that check out, it will try to clean up from the same place you are writing the current backups to. So that won't help.

## CopyOnly backups?

Using the CopyOnly parameter will prevent these one-off backups from affecting your backup chain. But the directory and/or filename will have a CopyOnly indicator in there, so the only old files that will get deleted are only going to be other CopyOnly backups.

## Modify the code?

You *might* be able to comment out the line that executes the "Backup Database..." command (something like `EXECUTE @CurrentCommandOutput =...`), and use the `Before_Backup` value for the CleanupMode parameter. That way, the cleanup will happen and then the backup will be skipped. However, there are a lot of checks in the code to prevent things from going sideways, and I haven't read through it in enough details to know if commenting out that line would be safe. I wouldn't recommend it.

## Let it work as designed?

Can you just correct the CleanupTime parameter that was too long, and let it clean everything up the next time it runs? Is there a reason you need to do the cleanup before the next scheduled backup?